# Error with initializing JFrame on subclipse

Tags: subclipse

[Error on JFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeKsX.png)

Can anyone help me about this problem?

Comment: Hello there! Seems like you're new here, it's fine, for us to actually help you, first can you actually add the code into the question instead of posting the image? So it should be easier for many people to help you, and actually imgur is blocked in my country so I need to use VPN to view that, and many people perhaps have the same problem, so it would be nice if you add some detail in the question instead of just posting image, thank you!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for comment on my first post,i will post new issue with code.